# Transmission Line Impedance 3 phase

Tags: impedance, transmission-line, three-phase, power-engineering, characteristic-impedance

I have the following question that I can't seem to figure out. The question ask to solve for the impedance of a 3ph transmission line. I've found the De (distance relative distance) and XL using the formula (u/2pi)*ln(De/GMR) and converted the unit. However, when it comes to the last step, this is where I went wrong (not sure if it is me or the answer key).

To find Z, I did
            Z = 10 mi *(Rac + jXL). From the table, Rac at 20C is .0693 (ohms/1000ft). When I converted it over to (ohms/mi), my Z = 3.65+6.21j

The solution used the Rdc but I thought this is a 3ph 60hz which is AC. Why are they using Rdc value from the table to solve for Z?? Please explain.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: R is not frequency dependent in this region.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? what do you mean by R is not dependent on the frequency? I thought frequency play a key role in resistance for AC problems

Comment: R at 60hz = Rdc in your case.

Comment: Rdc = .2993 and Rac = .3070. Two values are very close to each other and the answer come out to be comparable range. However, I dont understand why they are using the Rdc (which they have to convert to ohm/mile as well) instead of using the Rac value.